# Saving results to csv file: TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable

Tags: python-3.x, csv, nltk

I have extracted a list of names (not perfect but ok) using NLTK. I want to save these to a csv file but keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable
```

This is my code:

```
def get_human_names(text):
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    sentt = nltk.ne_chunk(pos)
    person_list = []
    person = []
    name = ""
    for subtree in sentt.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'PERSON'):
        for leaf in subtree.leaves():
            person.append(leaf[0])
        if len(person) > 1: #avoid grabbing lone surnames
            for part in person:
                name += part + ' '
            if name[:-1] not in person_list:
                person_list.append(name[:-1])
            name = ''
        person = []

    return (person_list)


def first_and_last_names(text):
    n = get_human_names(text)
    for name in n: 
        last_first = HumanName(name).last + ', ' + HumanName(name).first
       print(last_first)   

names = first_and_last_names(text)

Grayling, Chris
Hannant, Ruth
General, 
Services, Peter
Bogan, Gary
Parnership, Rail

import csv
with open('westtrannames.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerows(names)
csvFile.close()
```

I want a csv file with one row for the first name and the second row for the last name. Also, how would I append further results to the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of changes.

```
def first_and_last_names(text):
    n = get_human_names(text)
    result = []
    for name in n: 
        last_first = HumanName(name).last + ', ' + HumanName(name).first
        print(last_first)
        result.append([last_first])    #Append last_name to a list
    return result                    #Return list

names = first_and_last_names(text)

import csv
with open('westtrannames.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerows(names)          #Names should be a list now.
```

Comment: Thank you, I no longer get the error and it writes to the csv. But it's printing each character in a single cell i.e. C H R I S G R A Y L I N G - all going across in separate cells. Is there a line of code that would fix this?

Comment: There's some printed in the original question